# Why cant I define a variable inside a MATLAB anonymous function?

Tags: function, matlab, anonymous-function

I must be missing something really simple because this doesnt seem like it should be this hard.

This code is correct:

```
clear all
whatever = @(x) deal(max(x), size(x));
input = randn(1,1000);
[a b] = whatever(input)
```

However, what I really want to do is something like this:

```
clear all
whatever = @(x) deal(q = 3; q*max(x), size(x));
input = randn(1,1000);
[a b] = whatever(input)
```

Why does this break? I cant define q inside the function?? The whole reason I want to use anonymous functions is so that I can actually do multiple lines of code within them, and then return an answer. I suppose the last statement of an anonymous function is what is returned, but how do I define variables within them? I dont want to define q before the definition of the anonymous function.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot. What prevents you from doing `@(x)deal(3 * max(x), size(x))`?

Comment: @EitanT I _could_ do that. The reason I am asking is because I want q to be some_very_complicated_function, so it was going to be a place holder so that the code is readable in the end. I was under the impression I could code anonymous functions the same way I would actual functions. Its for readability of human.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot declare variables inside an anonymous function, because it must be constructed from an expression, *i.e.*: `handle = @(arglist)expr`

If you want readability, define `q` outside the function, like this:

```
q = 3;
whatever = @(x) deal(q * max(x), size(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't. Anonymous functions have only a single statement. You use subfunctions for that (not a nested function, those are sick things with strange scoping rules).

```
function whatever = not_anonymous (x)
  % your code here
end
```

If you need to pass function handles, you can just use `@not_anonymous`.

Comment: Hurray for nested functions! :p

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of following construct:

```
tmpfun = @(x,q) deal...
whatever = @(x) tmpfun(x,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure deal can't take in multiple commands.  Multiple parameters, sure, but you're trying to pass in commands.  Would this work?

```
whatever = @(x) q=3; deal(q*max(x), size(x));
```

Also, why wouldn't you just have this?

```
whatever = @(x) deal(3*max(x), size(x));
```

If you're going to define it within the function, you might as well just put the actual value there, if you can't get anything else to work.

Comment: _"Would this work?"_ -- are you asking or answering? BTW, the answer is: it won't work.

Comment: Camdroid, please seem my comment to @EitanT above. Its for future readability for human.